# spring bean should be sington is Good for Project?

Tags: spring

Why we are putting bean as signlton? there is no any concurrency issue occur ?

How we prevent

Comment: Not precise question! Give your use case or some specific details. Answers to this can be vast

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to make sure the singleton is thread safe. If it's not, then a singleton is probably not a good idea.

Comment: But if we put thread safe the it decrease performance of the application. Then why sign-ton is necessary for framework ?

Comment: @Patel: Synchronization and thread-safety are not the same thing.